# Why does using a large num for np.linspace mess up the calculation for intersection?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am attempting some calculations/graphing of two functions.

Using

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 35, 50)
g = lambda x: 155 * (1 + (5/100)) ** (x - 1)
f = lambda x: np.where(x<=25, 200, 0)

plt.plot(x, f(x), '-')
plt.plot(x, g(x), '-')

idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(f(x) - g(x)))).flatten()
plt.plot(x[idx], f(idx), 'ro')
plt.show()
print(x[idx],f(idx))
```

`>>> [5.71428571] [200]`
[image: attempt 1]

But that red dot isn't in the proper space (too far to the left).

So, assuming the issue is is the number of x-values, I change `x = np.linspace(0, 35, 100)` and get

`>>>[6.01010101] [200]`
[image: attempt 2]
which is better but still a bit off, and, in reality, I would like the exact solution.

But, if I change `x = np.linspace(0, 35, 200)`, I suddenly get

`>>>[6.15577889] [0]` and [image: attempt 3]
...which makes no sense to me.

Comment: `np.argwhere` returns index of non-zero elements so it gives you the last index where the sign is `1`, which is certainly not where the two curves intersect.

Comment: Also it should be `plt.plot(x[idx], f(x[idx]))`.

Comment: `argwhere` is totally fine.. The plot is done at `x[argwhere(..)]`, which is indeed the i-th index in `x` where the sign flips, i.e., where the curves are expected to intersect. Not exactly at point of intersection, but at "smallest x" following intersection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values of `g(x)`: There is no value equal to 200...

```
n = 50
           x        g(x)
7    5.000000  188.403469
8    5.714286  195.085103
9    6.428571  202.003699
10   7.142857  209.167659
-------------------------
n = 100
           x        g(x)
16  5.656566  194.536483
17  6.010101  197.921160
18  6.363636  201.364725
19  6.717172  204.868204
-------------------------
n = 200
           x        g(x)
34  5.979899  197.629730
35  6.155779  199.332925
36  6.331658  201.050798
37  6.507538  202.783475
```

Tip: use some function to solve the equation...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root_scalar


x = np.linspace(0, 35, 200)
g = lambda x: 155 * (1 + (5/100)) ** (x - 1)
f = lambda x: np.where(x<=25, 200, 0)
h = lambda x: f(x) - g(x)

plt.plot(x, f(x), '-')
plt.plot(x, g(x), '-')

idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(f(x) - g(x)))).flatten()
sol_object = root_scalar(h, bracket=[0., 10.])
x_root = sol_object.root

plt.plot(x[idx], f(x[idx]), 'ro', label='f(x[idx])')
plt.plot(x[idx], g(x[idx]), 'rx', label='g(x[idx])')
plt.plot(x_root, g(x_root), 'rD', label='g(x_root)')

plt.xlim(5., 7.5)
plt.ylim(100, 300)
plt.legend()

plt.show()
print(x[idx], f(x[idx]), g(x[idx]))
print(x_root, f(x_root), g(x_root))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!

I wasn't even smart enough to be asking about a better way to find the intersection---I'm going to have to spend some time understanding that scalar function and why it's the better method---but thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not sure if the function `root_scalar` is the best way to solve the problem, but it's a good option...

Answer (score 1):

The x-coordinate of your dot looks fine to me, just the y position does not.

It looks like you are plotting `f_i` (the i-th index), not `f(x)` (the evaluation of `f` at the i-th position of `x`.

Please plot `plt.plot(x[idx], f(x[idx]), 'ro')`, rather than `f(idx)`

Comment: Wow, I am so embarrassed!!

Thank you!